# Why is Font immutable?

Tags: c#, fonts, immutability

Font being immutable distresses both the programmer and the GC, because you need to create a new instance every time.

Why is Font an immutable reference type then?

Comment: I agree that something like `Label1.Font = new Font(Label1.Font.Name, Label1.Font.Size + 2.0F, Label1.Font.Style, Label1.Font.Unit);` seems a bit over the top from a "just do what I want" perspective.

Comment: Lets make credit card numbers immutable so anyone can change their number at anytime!!! what fun that would cause. And while your add it - lets make everyone's name immutable so we can change them every 5mins if we want.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It simplifies the usage from the render system.

If the framework were to allow Font to be mutable, it would need to detect changes, and rework how it's rendering happens on a regular basis.  Since Font creates a native resource, keeping this immutable prevents the system from worrying about having to recreate handles internally on a repeated basis.

Also, I disagree in terms of "Distress to the programmer".  By making Font immutable, it makes it more obvious what is happening when the user creates a Font object.  If you want a new Font, you need to create a new Font object, which in turn creates new native font resources.  Making Font immutable makes it more clear what is happening - you're less likely to create a performance problem accidentally.

Were Font mutable, it would be less obvious that you were creating handles repeatedly as you changed your Font properties.

Comment: Not to mention that any object (e.g. a Window) that uses the managed Font object would have to detect when the native handle had changed  and associate the new handle with its own native object (e.g. the HWND).

Comment: I always thought that copying & slightly changing an existing Font object was unnecessarily painful. I never considered that they create native resources, so +1 for the insightful answer.

Comment: too bad though they didn't make any AsBold() method which returns the a new instance only in bold.

Comment: @Itay: did you notice the [constructor that changes a font's style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdte89fc.aspx)?

Answer (score 14):

Well, ask yourself some questions.

First, is a font *logically* a mutable thing, like a grocery list, or an immutable thing, like a number?  If you are modelling a grocery list in a program, it makes sense to make it mutable because you typically think of having one grocery list the contents of which change as you run out of or purchase particular items.  But numbers you typically model as being immutable -- the number 12 is the number 12, now and forever.

I think of "Helvetica 12 point bold" as being a fixed, immutable thing, like a number, not something I can change.

Second, is a font *logically* more like a value that you can make copies of, or is it more like a single thing that you can refer to?  I don't think of having "two copies" of Helvetica; I think of referring to Helvetica. Whereas numbers I think of as having different copies of for different purposes -- when I have 12 items on my grocery list and 12 keys on my keyring, I don't think of both of those things as "referring to 12".

Since I think of fonts as being immutable and referred to, rather than as mutable and copied by value, I personally would model fonts as immutable reference types. Perhaps your intuitions about fonts are different than mine.

Comment: your philosophy of treating things seems to me irritatingly inconsistent. but i might have missed something... first, you're compering a general grocery list to a specific number. you can as well say that "watermelon, cheese, bread" will always be "watermelon, cheese and bread", while a number such as price, can be very variable....... a number might seem more atomic to us humans, but a grocery list is entity just like a number is a entity, they are both mutable AND immutable depending on context. just like true will always be true but a lamp can be either on or off...... [continued]

Comment: [part2] now is boolean LOGICALLY immutable? this question just unanswerable. the only things that matter are practical considerations............. now "Helvetica 12 point bold" is really as fixed thing. just like true, and the number 12. but the font of my title is varible, just like a price of a car or the state of a lamb...... secondly,  in fact you CAN have in C# two copies of "Helvetica 12 point bold" and you ARE referring numbers in java........ logic should be a consideration that helps to get to aesthetic results, but in the end you should be guided by practical consideration.

Comment: @Itay: When my wife asks me to add milk to the grocery list I do not destroy the old list and produce a new list with milk added. The list is mutable, and so it makes sense to model a grocery list with a mutable type. There are of course contexts in which modelling lists as immutable makes sense.

Comment: @Eric - I think that's an unanswerable philosophical question.  If we take a view "outside of time", then arguably all versions of the list can coexist, indexed by time, and your changing the list today doesn't alter yesterday's list.  To me the relevant question is "Does this model of the world simplify the solution to the problem at hand?", which will depend on the context.

Comment: @kvb: You buy your groceries in the Platonic eternal world of ideal forms, outside of time? That would certainly solve the wilted lettuce problem.

Comment: putting things in an everyday basis context in such level is just WEIRD... your comparisons, to me, are just not sensible, i can as much say that when i fix a spelling mistake in my written essay i don't destroy the old one a create a new one fixed, but in fact that exactly what string.Replace does... IMO those comparisons just have nothing to do with the way you should design classes.... i mean, sometimes i too try to think about what DOES my class represent and what's the most sensible way to design it and not only practical considerations... but you are taking it to a whole new level..

Comment: @Eric: when i write a title, and then decided to add an underline, would i destroy the old title and create a new one? now that's just a stupid question which derivative from your way

Comment: @Itay: I think that these things are very important when designing classes. I don't require you to agree with me. If these comparisons are unhelpful to you, don't use them. Your example of a document editing system is good; if I were writing such a system I might model a document as being a mutable object, since that's how users think of documents. However, I might also model it as an immutable object because that would enable me to build a rich undo-redo system more easily. That's an engineering decision that I would consider carefully; there are many pros and cons of both sides.

Answer (score 8):

They aren't structures because they need to have finalizers to wrap the underlying objects and provide a sensible `IDisposable` implementation. What happens if you `Dispose()` your own copy of a `struct`? Do you clone the handle each time?

It isn't really much stress on the GC...

It also allows the `Font` to be re-used safely without worry about it changing half way through an operation ;-p

Comment: What would have been helpful would have been to have a mutable FontInfo struct, and an immutable ReadyFont class; only the latter would need disposing.  Things like the Font properties on controls would be exposed as a FontInfo struct, rather than as a ReadyFont.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree this distresses the programmer.  There are plenty of immutable types in the BCL which are used on a daily basis by programmers and don't cause any issues.  System.String for example.

One of the benefits of being immutable is that you don't have to create a new instance every time.  You can re-use the same Font type as often as you like because it's not going to change.  On the other hand, if it were mutable, you would need to make a copy every time to help guarantee that no one else changed it out from under you.

Lastly, Font is not actually an immutable class in the strictest sense of the word.  It implements IDisposable and in the Dispose method tears down the underlying native object.

Comment: That reminds me of something I've wondered about: who "owns" fonts, images, and other objects that are used in controls?  If I create a font and assign it to a control's Font property, does it copy the passed-in Font so I should Dispose the font once I no longer need it, or should I keep a reference to the font around until I dispose the control or assign it a different font, so I can Dispose the font properly?  My normal approach is to simply abandon objects I'm assigning into a control and let the GC handle them, but that feels icky.

Comment: @supercat I've never understood the answer to who owns `Font` either and I don't believe there is a good answer.  I have the same approach of abandon and let the GC pick them up.

Comment: I forget whether I said this before, but the Font property of a control seems to sample the properties of the font without regard for whether the Font is disposed.  One can Dispose a font object and still set a Control.Font property to the disposed font.

Comment: i meant distress in the syntax

Answer (score 0):

You could argue that it distresses the developer. But you could also make the same argument in the opposite case.

For example:

```
// Let me just set the button to the same font as the textbox...
button.Font = textBox.Font;

// ...except that I want the button's font to be bold.
button.Font.Bold = true;
```

The above code would set a button and a textbox's font to bold at the same time if `Font` were mutable, contrary to the developer's expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Font is a poorly designed object, which violates the Single Responsibility Principle, and the difficulties you cite stem from this.  The problem with Font is that it encompasses two things: (1) a description of how a font should be drawn, and (2) a GDI font object for a font with those properties.  The former type could be mutable without consequence, while making the latter type mutable would pose all sorts of problems.

Among other things, consider the question of how one should track the ownership of a typical control (e.g Button) Font property?  If one will sometimes change the fonts associated with controls, should one create a separate Font object for each control, and Dispose of it when changing a control's font to something else, or should one keep a list of all the different fonts one is using so as to avoid creating an excessive number of identical Font objects, or what?

If there existed a FontDescription struct (which was mutable, and not IDisposable) and things like Control.Font were of type FontDescription (or better yet, Control exposed a SetFont method with parameter of type FontDescription), the above question could be answered pretty simply.  As it is, the most efficient approach for setting the Font of a control is to create a new font object (if one doesn't already have a suitable one), immediately Dispose it, and then do the assignment.  The "font description" part of the Font remains quasi-valid even after Disposal, and that's all that's really needed for the Control.Font property.