# Why is the RichTextBox's Font.Size property editable at design-time, but readonly at compile time?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, richtextbox, font-size

This code:

```
private void comboBoxFontSize_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    rtbResults.Font.Size = Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxFontSize.SelectedItem);
}
```

...generates this err msg: *"Property or indexer 'System.Drawing.Font.Size' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"*

### UPDATE

After attempting the suggested fix, I get this at runtime:

System.FormatException was unhandled
  Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, 
...

Okay, I see: I was using Convert.ToInt32() but the first value in the comboBox was "8.25" -which is, obviously, not an int.

So I tried Convert.ToDouble() and that won't compile.

Then I see in the intellisense hints that *"Calling this method* always throws 'System.InvalidCastException'"*

- as well as Convert.ToSingle()

So must I change my combobox value from 8.25 to 8? 8.25 is the default value...???

### UPDATED AGAIN

I read over the weekend (in Petzold's WP7 book, I think) that 8.25 corresponds to 11. So the 8.25 referred to here is, I think, pixels, which corresponds to font size of 11, which makes a lot more sense now (although still rather overly misleading/confusing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cause Font is immutable...

[Why is Font immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561126/why-is-font-immutable)

use

```
rtbResults.Font = new Font(rtbResults.Font.FontFamily, Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxFontSize.SelectedItem), 
rtbResults.Font.Style)
```

or another Font constructor as you need.

Comment: Once I changed "rtbResults.Font.FontStyle" to "rtbResults.Font.Style" it compiled, but at run time I get:

System.FormatException was unhandled
  Message=Input string was not in a correct format..."

the rest of the err msg is added above, appended to the original post.

Comment: well you must have an error in `Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxFontSize.SelectedItem)` . What about `Convert.toInt32(comboBoxFontSize.SelectedValue)`. Or at least check what you have in your SelectedItem before converting...

Comment: Okay, I exchanged my update with a new update - the val was not an int.

Comment: Changing the items to all ints (8..12) and using SelectedItem, it now works; SelectedValue fails, because that is viewed as being "0" which is value-non-grata for the "em" argument.